# Android Eclipse failing to debug

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Debugging of my app is now suddenly broken.  It has been fine up to now and I even reloaded a known good version of my entire code and it still fails to debug or even run.  When I hit debug or run the app starts up and right when it is about to display the app, it crashes (before even entering the main view).  I have a break point on the first line of code and it never even reaches it.  It just goes to Source not found - The source attachment does not contains the source for the file DexFile.class.....
I am 100% certain all the code I have loaded is working, as it is a saved backup which was saved when last working.

Also, what is odd is that if I unplug the cable at this point, the app loads normally and works fine.  So this is definitely a debugging issue.  It is getting stuck somewhere at boot.  I have restarted my computer and phone several times to no avail.

```
LogCat:
`04-04 11:17:33.462: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4148): CheckJNI is OFF
04-04 11:17:33.462: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4148): creating instr width table
04-04 11:17:33.502: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4148): --- registering native functions ---
04-04 11:17:33.712: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4148): Shutting down VM
04-04 11:17:33.712: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4148): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-04 11:17:33.712: INFO/AndroidRuntime(4148): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-04 11:17:33.902: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4157): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
04-04 11:17:33.902: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4157): CheckJNI is OFF
04-04 11:17:33.902: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4157): creating instr width table
04-04 11:17:33.942: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4157): --- registering native functions ---
04-04 11:17:34.152: INFO/Process(107): Sending signal. PID: 4137 SIG: 9
04-04 11:17:34.152: INFO/ActivityManager(107): Force stopping package org.scanner uid=10110
04-04 11:17:34.162: ERROR/ActivityManager(107): fail to set top app changed!
04-04 11:17:34.182: INFO/UsageStats(107): Unexpected resume of com.htc.launcher while already resumed in org.scanner
04-04 11:17:34.192: INFO/ActivityManager(107): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.obdscanner/.activity.ObdReaderMainActivity }
04-04 11:17:34.202: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4157): Shutting down VM
04-04 11:17:34.202: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4157): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-04 11:17:34.212: INFO/AndroidRuntime(4157): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-04 11:17:34.222: WARN/InputManagerService(107): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@464105d8
04-04 11:17:34.242: INFO/ActivityManager(107): Start proc org.scanner for activity org.obdscanner/.activity.ReaderMainActivity: pid=4165 uid=10110 gids={3003, 3002}
04-04 11:17:34.332: WARN/ActivityThread(4165): Application org.scanner is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-04 11:17:34.332: INFO/System.out(4165): Sending WAIT chunk
04-04 11:17:34.352: INFO/dalvikvm(4165): Debugger is active
04-04 11:17:34.472: DEBUG/Norton Community Watch/smrsd(3910): smrsd broadcast intent success!
04-04 11:17:34.512: ERROR/(3910): /data/data/com.symantec.monitor/app_log_item/1301930254.txt//data/data/com.symantec.monitor/app_log_item
04-04 11:17:34.542: INFO/System.out(4165): Debugger has connected
04-04 11:17:34.542: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:34.632: INFO/global(3898): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
04-04 11:17:34.742: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:34.862: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3898): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4492 objects / 274560 bytes in 41ms
04-04 11:17:34.942: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:35.142: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:35.342: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:35.552: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:35.752: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:35.952: INFO/System.out(4165): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-04 11:17:36.157: INFO/System.out(4165): debugger has settled (1451)
04-04 11:17:37.296: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4165): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
```

`

Comment: Have you try clean project or reboot adb or restart eclipse ?

Comment: Yes I have cleaned, rebooted phone, rebooted computer, etc

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Symantec stuff? Or uninstalling Norton, or whatever you have running? it's the only error I'm seeing in the LogCat output. I wonder if it's prematurely killing your app for some reason?

Comment: Are you sure it's a crash dialog and not an "waiting for debug" dialog which appears ? I say that because the end of your log is `waiting for debugger...`

Comment: I have uninstalled the Norton Utilities app and that had no effect. The waiting for debug dialog does appear, then it goes away and I am left at a blank screen at which point I get the DexFile.class Source not found error. Then, if I unplug the cable, the app loads.

Comment: SOLVED!  Strange solution...I just closed the project from package explorer, then removed it from the workspace.  Closed Eclipse.  Re-opened Eclipse and imported the project.  All is good now.  Very strange, especially since PC reboot and phone reboots didnt even solve the issue.  Crazy that simply removing the app from package explorer and added it back did the trick.

Comment: @Jesse: Would you mind posting your solution as answer to your question (you may even later accept it), so that a) it no longer lingers as open question and b) other users may learn from it as well.

Comment: @Jesse I second Heiko's comment. Your solution worked for me and I nearly left the page without noticing it after neither answer did it for me. Thanks either way

Comment: @Jesse I third this, worked great after eclipse crashed and got itself into a twist. Almost didnt see the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Please see the correct annswer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502445/dexfile-class-error-in-eclipse)

You have set a break point in one of the classes. Just take off all the break points in your project and run again, their will be no problem.

Eclipse->Window->Show View->(Other->Debug->)Breakpoints

Answer (score 8):

Occasionally Eclipse and the various Android development plug-ins will become out of sync. I usually attempt the following when debugging / development gets "funky"

1. If your Logcat is not displaying lines, clear it. It has a small buffer. Also ensure that your device is selected in the "DDMS" perspective. If you have the emulator selected you will only receive logging from it.
2. Clean and Rebuild all open projects. Ensure there are no errors.
3. Uninstall the application from the remote device/emulator.
4. Restart Eclipse!
5. Open a terminal on your platform and use the tool `adb` in the "platform-tools" directory.

   ```
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server
   ```
6. Stash your working copy and revert your source code if using a repository.

Answer (score 4):

Strange solution...I just closed the project from package explorer, then removed it from the workspace. Closed Eclipse. Re-opened Eclipse and imported the project.

(Copy and pasted from Jesse's comment.)

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above, but i turned out that it was not working due to **multiple instances** of eclipse.exe
Killing them all in the **task manager** (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC) solved it.

Answer (score 1):

On your Android device (or emulator) go to:

```
Applications - Settings - Applications - Manage applications - All
```

There you have to select your app and uninstall it.

Afterwards try to run your app from the IDE again. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new debug configuration of type `Remote Java Application` and set it to localhost and the port you see on the DDMS window.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13421917/624109

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late.... use it if @Sam's or @Killesk's answers do not work.

1. ensure the manifest sets [`android:debuggable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).
2. In `onCreate`, add a call to [Debug.waitForDebugger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html).

Adding the call to `waitForDebugger` also works when reversing. For example you can add the following by hand in `onCreate` and have smali/baksmali recompile it:

```
invoke-static {}, Landroid/os/Debug;->waitForDebugger()V
```

I don't have to use the tricks often, but when I do, `waitForDebugger` always works. I don't recall a time I could not snap the debugger with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen due to my code being obfuscated.  I didn't notice that someone had changed proguard.cfg for a production release and commented-out the "-dontobfuscate" line.