# The Jar file ../android-8/android.jar has no source attachment

Tags: java, android

I came across this no source attachment problem when I was debugging the project, but when I run the android program without debugging enabled, the program would run without any trouble.  Even after I attached the jar file manually, it still reported that properties.class could not be found! What should I do with this problem? What is the reason for this? thanks!!!

Daniel

Answer (score 3):

In the debug mode your application try to go through all the sources. Some of these sources are come from parts of Android framework system (Android SDK) which has been built. Thus, they come to your system as a built files (there are no source files) and thus, when you try to step through a function from Android framework the system cannot find the sources of this function (but still you have binaries of this function).

To avoid this problem during the debug you can download and attach the sources of Android system or you can use Android Sources plugin (http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/)

Comment: Thanks, Yury! I am installing the Android Sources plugin. I think it will work.

Comment: This plugin is what I needed to follow the debug into Android source code! It just takes a little time to download about 240MB but it is worth every byte!

Comment: @ilomambo Just downloaded the plugin, but still getting the same error.  Using eclipse juno.  Did you have to do anything else once you installed the plugin ilomambo?

Comment: Ended up getting my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540670/android-eclipse-failing-to-debug/15454248#15454248).

Comment: @nissemand Glad to hear it. Anyway, this answer is outdated. The Android SDK, since several versions ago, started to come with all the sources included and if the debugger does not find them, on the same debugger window you'll find a button to add them to your project.