# Source not found : SQLiteCursor.class

Tags: java, android

Running in Debug and pressing F8 to continue will get this 'Class File Editor - Source not found error'

```
// Compiled from SQLiteCursor.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor extends     android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor {

// Method descriptor #8 (Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;Landroid/database/sqlite    /SQLiteCursorDriver;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteQuery;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 5
  public SQLiteCursor(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db,     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver driver, java.lang.String editTable, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery query);
     0  aload_0 [this]
 1  invokespecial android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor() [1]
 4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 7  dup
 8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
13  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 5]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: db index: 1 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: driver index: 2 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: editTable index: 3 type: java.lang.String
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: query index: 4 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery

// Method descriptor #23 (Landroid/database/DataSetObserver;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 2
public void registerDataSetObserver(android.database.DataSetObserver observer);
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 6]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: observer index: 1 type: android.database.DataSetObserver

// Method descriptor #27 ()Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
public android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase getDatabase();
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 7]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

// Method descriptor #29 (II)Z
// Stack: 3, Locals: 3
public boolean onMove(int oldPosition, int newPosition);
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 8]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: oldPosition index: 1 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: newPosition index: 2 type: int

// Method descriptor #34 ()I
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
public int getCount();
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 9]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

// Method descriptor #36 (Ljava/lang/String;)I
// Stack: 3, Locals: 2
public int getColumnIndex(java.lang.String columnName);
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 10]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: columnName index: 1 type: java.lang.String

// Method descriptor #39 ()[Ljava/lang/String;
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
public java.lang.String[] getColumnNames();
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 11]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

// Method descriptor #41 ()V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
public void deactivate();
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 12]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

// Method descriptor #41 ()V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
public void close();
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 13]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

// Method descriptor #44 ()Z
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
public boolean requery();
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 14]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

// Method descriptor #46 (Landroid/database/CursorWindow;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 2
public void setWindow(android.database.CursorWindow window);
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 15]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: window index: 1 type: android.database.CursorWindow

// Method descriptor #50 ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 2
public void setSelectionArguments(java.lang.String[] selectionArgs);
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 16]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: selectionArgs index: 1 type: java.lang.String[]

// Method descriptor #41 ()V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
protected void finalize();
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 3  dup
 4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 17]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
```

}

I don't understand what this is telling me.

If I press F8 a few more times, the program continues along as normal and displays data and results as I would expect.

How do I read this error so that I can make effective fixes to my code?

Thanks

Comment: Is it asking for `Attach source`? It looks like you are going to debug  some `.class` file whose source is not attached to your jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652690/the-jar-file-android-8-android-jar-has-no-source-attachment) got rid of the impenetrable message and attached the class file.

Which then helped me identify a cursor not closed error.