# Android: (java) 2D array of object / including custom class / debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, android, debugging, multidimensional-array, import

I don´t know if my problem is in icluding file with class, in the class, or in using them.
I have a simple class:

```
public class Entry {
char ZNAK;
boolean volno;

Entry() {
    this.volno = true;
}

// setter
void setZNAK(char z) {
    this.ZNAK = z;
}

// getter
char znak() {return ZNAK; }
boolean volno() {return volno; }
}
```

in separate file that I added to my package in src folder in Eclipse to the other.
and in next file, have

```
   public static Entry[][] matrix;
```

and in method

```
matrix = new Entry[Height][Width];
```

and in loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
    { 
        for(int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
        { 
            matrix[i][j] = new Entry();
            matrix[i][j].setZNAK(Character.toUpperCase(/*character here*/));
        }
    }
```

Eclipse don't show any errors, but it crashed. And second problem is that I can not debug it, when i try the Class File Editor appear.

> **Source not found**
>   The Jaf file C:\Users..\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar has no source attachment

and some [log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20995054/android.log) below.

Comment: I believe the "Source not found" implies it can't find an android system to run the application. As per this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652690/the-jar-file-android-8-android-jar-has-no-source-attachment) there are some links to addons you can download.

Comment: I read this article and installed the addons but still same problem. Code is working, because without debuging everything going fine.

EDIT: and I forgot tell, that the problem to see the code is only on the my custom class, others is OK