# Android AsyncTask will not work downloading image

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am hoping someone can help me with a problem I have been having. I am in the process of making my app work on versions greater than 3.0 so I can only perform GUI tasks on the UI Thread. I have got the following code, I am getting no compile errors but it is not working. In the log I get the following error:

**I/AndroidRuntime(464): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed**

Thank you for your help!

```
new DownloadImageTask().execute(imgURL); //imgURL is declared as string URL

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCity)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
     }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return loadImage(params[0]);
    }

}


public Bitmap loadImage(String poiURLimg) {

    try {
        URL ulrn = new URL(poiURLimg);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        if (null != bmp)
        return bmp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Is your app crashing, or just not exhibiting the behavior you expect?

Comment: *NEVER* use an empty `catch` block. At the very least use `e.printStackTrace()` so you can check logcat to see if an `Exception` is being caught.

Comment: The app is not crashing, it is just not displaying the image. I get no compile errors also.

Comment: @Squonk I have added this in and i am getting no exceptions in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to try. First, make sure you've added the INTERNET permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file. You'll need that to download images from the internet and your app will crash without it (although it doesn't sound like this is your issue)

Try using this for your loadImage() method:

```
public static Bitmap loadImage(String src)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of a DownloadImageTask that I wrote and use in my apps currently (so I know it works correctly):

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        return loadImage(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
        if (isCancelled() || result == null)
            return;

        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view)).setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It isn't the internet permission because it was working before I put it into the AsyncTask - I did check and the permission is still there in the manifest. I also tried your code for loadImage and still getting the same result, it is just an empty image view. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with my full AsyncTask code that works for me.

Comment: Thanks for this, It is working now with the code you have put in your comment above.

Answer (score 1):

The Binder Thread #3 error is not related to the code in your app. There are a number of potential causes usually related to something in eclipse. You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540670/android-eclipse-failing-to-debug) which gives some examples.

As to why the Bitmap wont load - in your `onPostExecute` you are setting the Bitmap for that `ImageView` to bmp. Bmp is name of the value that your loadImage method creating the bitmap returns. It is not the name of the Bitmap you pass as an argument into `onPosExecute` - that is Bitmap result. Change bmp to result and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I have changed the code as you suggest to this code below, and there is still the same problem that the image does not appear: `((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCity)).setImageBitmap(result);`

Comment: You're not actually referring to a `View` with that code. Is the `ImageView` declared elsewhere? You need to use ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCity) to get the `View` then set the image.

Comment: Thank you again, I have run it with this change and it is still not showing, I changed the code to what you suggested above:
`ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCity);
 image.setImageBitmap(result);`