# Not able to debug android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

While debugging I have faced an issue .I have placed toggle break points on various places but when I start debugging the execution of code is not getting stop at break point .I am facing this problem from two days and  was running before .I tried after closing of project also the option of skip all break point in run menu is unchecked .Also have not found **android:process=":remote"** in manifiest Please help me.

Additional Info : I dont know it is related or not but  there are two packages are visible in device information .First package has debug symbol with it and port number 8600 where as second package has port number 8601/8700 .Might be there are port number issue .

Break points is working  when I put it on launching activity . But not working when I put break points on service and receivers .

Logcat :

```
01-08 10:45:54.481: I/System.out(15653): Sending WAIT chunk
01-08 10:45:54.481: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x4032c509, tls=0x53824f00, arg=0x4079b360
01-08 10:45:54.481: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x4032c509
01-08 10:45:54.481: D/libc(15653): , tls=0x53824f00, arg=0x4079b360
01-08 10:45:54.681: I/System.out(15653): Debugger has connected
01-08 10:45:54.681: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:54.881: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:55.081: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:55.281: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:55.481: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:55.681: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:55.881: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:56.081: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:56.281: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:56.491: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:56.691: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:56.891: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:57.091: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:57.291: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:57.491: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:57.691: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:57.891: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:58.091: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:58.291: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:58.491: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:58.701: I/System.out(15653): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-08 10:45:58.901: I/System.out(15653): debugger has settled (1477)
01-08 10:46:00.761: I/ActivityThread(15653): Pub com.csipsimple.prefs: com.csipsimple.service.PreferenceProvider
01-08 10:46:00.821: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40c1483d, tls=0x53c65f00, arg=0x40318f60
01-08 10:46:00.821: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40c1483d
01-08 10:46:00.821: D/libc(15653): , tls=0x53c65f00, arg=0x40318f60
01-08 10:46:01.421: E/siphome(15653): sip home
01-08 10:46:01.961: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40c1483d, tls=0x53c65f00, arg=0x50fe9118
01-08 10:46:01.961: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40c1483d
01-08 10:46:01.961: D/libc(15653): , tls=0x53c65f00, arg=0x50fe9118
01-08 10:46:01.981: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40c1483d, tls=0x53d65f00, arg=0x4079c610
01-08 10:46:01.991: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40c1483d
01-08 10:46:01.991: D/libc(15653): , tls=0x53d65f00, arg=0x4079c610
01-08 10:46:01.991: E/starting thread(15653): starting thread 
01-08 10:46:02.111: E/Trace(15754): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-08 10:46:02.211: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40c1483d, tls=0x53e65f00, arg=0x50f33650
01-08 10:46:02.231: D/libc(15653): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40c1483d
01-08 10:46:02.231: D/libc(15653): , tls=0x53e65f00, arg=0x50f33650
01-08 10:46:02.381: I/ActivityThread(15754): Pub com.csipsimple.db: com.csipsimple.db.DBProvider
01-08 10:46:02.481: I/Adreno200-EGL(15653): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.081_msm7627a_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL2820657_release_AU (CL2820657)
```

Comment: please check [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279137) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540670/android-eclipse-failing-to-debug), you may get some ideas, btw are you debugging on emulator or real device?

Comment: @RDC I am debugging on  real device

Comment: Its VERY slow to run the emulator in debug mode, some things just time out and fail more often than they would not in debug mode. You should rather learn to put a lot of logs in the code to find the errors. Typed this comment before you posted yours. Further more, the debugger on eclipse is not the best.

Comment: @NicolasTyler I have put logs but this time I actully need to debug it

Comment: where have you put your breakpoints. You are running SIP based application through CSIPSimple, if I am right, it can be or might be the issue with JNI if you are using it.

Comment: @Yes you are right .But how to find issue as app is running properly and debugging was running properly before two days .

Comment: Sorry, but I am afraid I'll not be able to help you there. I am also stuck while compiling PJSIP on ubuntu, facing some error.

Comment: @VishwasSharma Its ok no problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you can try:

- Clean and rebuild the project
- make sure your debug config is all correct.
- make sure the selected java sdk is up to date.
- increase your heap size that eclipse may use.
- restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing all you breakpoints that you put in your code following this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-removeall_viewaction.htm).