# Waiting for Debugger to Settle... message then VM Shutdown

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, dalvik

I'm starting to learn programming for android.I'm trying to connect an Android app to a SSL-enabled server. I take article as an example.(http://adblogcat.com/ssl-sockets-android-and-server-using-a-certificate/). I have an error occurs, the program terminates with the words "unfortunately has stopped"

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

/* Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText iptxt;
Button sendbtn;
TextView logtxt;
EditText porttxt;
EditText cmdtxt;

// port to use
private String ip_address;
private int port = 1992;
private String cmdstr = null;
private SSLSocket socket = null;
private BufferedWriter out = null;
private BufferedReader in = null;
private final String TAG = "TAG";
private String keystorepass = "mypasswordisCOOL!";
private String keypassword = "mypasswordRULEZ@";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iptxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iptxt);
    porttxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.porttxt);
    cmdtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cmdtxt);

    logtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logtxt);

    sendbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);

    sendbtn.setClickable(true);
    sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (iptxt.getText().toString().equals(null) || porttxt.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please enter an IP address or Port number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
               cmdstr = cmdtxt.getText().toString();
               if (cmdstr == null) {
                   Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "No command was entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }

                Log.i(TAG, "makes it to here");

                port = Integer.parseInt(porttxt.getText().toString());
                ip_address = iptxt.getText().toString();

                try {

                    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
                    InputStream key = v.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mykeyandroid);
                    ks.load(key,keystorepass.toCharArray());
                    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(ks);
                    socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
                    socket = (SSLSocket)
                            socketFactory.createSocket(new Socket(ip_address,port), ip_address, port, false);
                    socket.startHandshake();


                    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    chat(cmdstr);

                    key.close();
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    socket.close();

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Unknown host", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unknown host");
                    //System.exit(1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "No I/O", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "No I/O");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //System.exit(1);
                } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Keystore ks error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Keystore ks error");
                    //System.exit(-1);
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "No such algorithm for ks.load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "No such algorithm for ks.load");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //System.exit(-1);
                } catch (CertificateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "certificate missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "certificate missing");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //System.exit(-1);
                } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "KeyManagementException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "key management exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //System.exit(-1);
                } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "UnrecoverableKeyException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG,"unrecoverableKeyException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }
    });

}


public void chat(String temp){
    String message = temp;
    String line = "";
    // send id of the device to match with the image
    try {
        out.write(message);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Read failed");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    // receive a ready command from the server
    try {
        line = in.readLine();
        logtxt.setText("SERVER SAID: " + line);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Read failed");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

This is log:

```
06-05 22:30:17.553      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-05 22:30:17.874      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application W/ActivityThread﹕ Application ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-05 22:30:17.903      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
06-05 22:30:18.163      543-550/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
06-05 22:30:18.305      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
06-05 22:30:18.305      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:18.502      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:18.702      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:18.912      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:19.114      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:19.312      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:19.516      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:19.717      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 22:30:19.918      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1340)
06-05 22:30:21.642      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-05 22:30:21.722      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application W/TextLayoutCache﹕ computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
06-05 22:30:43.273      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application I/TAG﹕ makes it to here
06-05 22:30:43.273      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-05 22:30:43.282      543-543/ru.nightvolks.nvclienttls.application W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
```

Server code taken from an article. Help me please correct the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Eclipse failing to debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540670/android-eclipse-failing-to-debug)

Comment: Also... does the app have the Debuggable flag set? See [Can not set debuggable flag in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986724/can-not-set-debuggable-flag-in-androidmanifest-xml). Does the app have `INTERNET` permission? See [What permission do I need to access Internet from an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application).

Comment: Waiting for the debugger to settle isn't very interesting.  The exception is, but that starts below the last line in the log snippet included above.  You need to identify the exception and what line it's failing on.  If it's not in the log then it's presumably stopped in the debugger and you can get the information from there.