# IllegalArgumentException and "thread still suspended after undo" after returning empty SQLite cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, dalvik

When running my android application the ContentProvider returns an empty SQLite cursor (zero rows). This results in `dalvikvm` outputting the following message in LogCat:

```
threadid=1 still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

The debug tab in Eclipse show the following exception:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalArgumentException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(Object) line: 63 
    AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask(ModernAsyncTask).finish(Object) line: 461  
    ModernAsyncTask.access$500(ModernAsyncTask, Object) line: 47    
    ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 474    
    ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99  
    Looper.loop() line: 213 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5225    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 741  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 557 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I've logged every action in the `OffersDatabaseHelper.OffersDatabaseHelper` class. The method `query` returns a cursor to `android.content.ContentProvider`'s method `query` wich seems to be the cause of the problem.

### LogCat output:

```
03-13 14:12:20.116: I/System.out(2521): Sending WAIT chunk
03-13 14:12:20.116: I/dalvikvm(2521): Debugger is active
03-13 14:12:20.316: I/System.out(2521): Debugger has connected
03-13 14:12:20.316: I/System.out(2521): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-13 14:12:20.516: I/System.out(2521): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-13 14:12:20.716: I/System.out(2521): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-13 14:12:20.916: I/System.out(2521): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-13 14:12:21.117: I/System.out(2521): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-13 14:12:21.317: I/System.out(2521): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-13 14:12:21.517: I/System.out(2521): debugger has settled (1311)
03-13 14:12:21.537: V/OffersContentProvider(2521): onCreate called
03-13 14:12:21.537: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): setting context
03-13 14:12:21.537: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): setting dbHelper
03-13 14:12:21.537: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): initiating OffersDatabaseHelper
03-13 14:12:21.537: V/OffersContentProvider(2521): OffersDatabaseHelper.OffersDatabaseHelper called
03-13 14:12:21.557: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Returning if offersDB is null
03-13 14:12:21.557: D/OffersContentProvider(2521): false
03-13 14:12:21.937: V/OffersContentProvider(2521): query called
03-13 14:12:21.977: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): CallerClassName=android.content.ContentProvider , Caller method name: query
03-13 14:12:21.987: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Callee method name: query
03-13 14:12:21.987: D/OffersContentProvider - query - uri(2521): content://com.example.provider.offers/offers
03-13 14:12:21.997: D/OffersContentProvider - query - projection(2521): [offer_id, offer_title, offer_description, offer_distance, offer_icon, offer_reference]
03-13 14:12:22.007: D/OffersContentProvider - query - selection(2521): null
03-13 14:12:22.007: D/OffersContentProvider - query - selectionArgs(2521): null
03-13 14:12:22.007: D/OffersContentProvider - query - sort(2521): null
03-13 14:12:22.007: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Instantiating SQLiteQueryBuilder with table offers
03-13 14:12:22.017: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Instantiating SQLIteQueryBuilder succesful
03-13 14:12:22.017: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Trying to match uri with 2
03-13 14:12:22.027: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Could not match with uri
03-13 14:12:22.027: D/OffersContentProvider(2521): 1
03-13 14:12:22.027: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Preparing orderBy
03-13 14:12:22.027: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): sort is empty, orderBy will be offer_distance ASC
03-13 14:12:22.027: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Preparing to query the underlying database
03-13 14:12:22.027: D/libEGL(2521): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
03-13 14:12:22.027: D/libEGL(2521): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
03-13 14:12:22.027: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Querying underlying database successful
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Dumping cursor
03-13 14:12:22.038: D/libEGL(2521): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
03-13 14:12:22.038: D/OffersContentProvider(2521): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41b8afa0
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/Adreno-EGL(2521): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/Adreno-EGL(2521): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/Adreno-EGL(2521): Build Date: 12/01/13 Sun
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/Adreno-EGL(2521): Local Branch: 
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/Adreno-EGL(2521): Remote Branch: 
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/Adreno-EGL(2521): Local Patches: 
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/Adreno-EGL(2521): Reconstruct Branch: 
03-13 14:12:22.038: D/OffersContentProvider(2521): Cursor has 0 rows
03-13 14:12:22.038: I/OffersContentProvider(2521): Returing cursor
03-13 14:12:22.078: D/OpenGLRenderer(2521): Enabling debug mode 0
03-13 14:12:23.069: D/dalvikvm(2521): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

### Miscellaneous details:

- This problem occurs both on virtual devices and the Sony Xperia Z I'm testing with
- Android min-sdk = 11, target-sdk = 19

Any input on how to solve this problem is more than welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: There are two separate things going on: (1) you're getting an exception, and (2) the interaction with the debugger is slightly weird. Which of them are you trying to debug? If #1, you can set an exception breakpoint on `IllegalArgumentException` (with "stop all threads" = true) to stop the VM at the point where the exception is first thrown, rather than the last point where it was re-thrown. (By default, the VM doesn't stop unless the exception is uncaught, so code that catches and re-throws will conceal the initial cause.) You can ignore the "still suspended" message (note it's at 'D' level).

Comment: Thank you, fadden. I just found out what caused the exception. I'll post my answer below.

Comment: Cool.  For #2, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649282/interpretate-logcat-entry-threadid-8-still-suspended-after-undo-sc-1-dc-1-s-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to dig I have just found out what is the cause of this particular problem. The debugger showed that SQLite gave me an exception telling me that the field `_id` was not present, wich was quite a surprise to me because my primary key wasn't `_id`.

Thanks to [Al Sutton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3192129/540812) on a different question I became aware that the primary field in my table was different from what `SQLiteOpenHelper` requires/

Changing the primary field to `_id` solved my problem.